# Spectrogram[Array] a espectrograma en 3D, Listplot3d

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Tengo una duda en `wolfram mathematica`. Lo que pasa es que tengo un arreglo de datos y puedo generar un `espectrograma`, lo que necesito es generar este mismo espectrograma en 3 dimensiones,

> Espectrograma en 2D

[image: Spectrogram[arreglo]...]

> Espectrograma 3D (que deseo obtener)

Lo que deseo es lograr algo como en la siguiente imagen

[image]

Lo he logrado con archivos `.WAV` pero no con una columna de excel con datos, la cual importe a mathematica, sólo logré aplicar filtros y hacer el `spectrograma` en 2D. Si alguien me pudiera dar una ayudadita lo agradecería. Muchas gracias.

> **Edición** (Agregaré lo que tengo respecto a la duda)

Estoy dando uso del código que está en el siguiente link, pero creo que no  entiendo bien los parámetros de entrada para la función, no logro que funcione para el archivo **.csv**. Es probable que esté haciendo todo mal y no sea esta la función que debo usar, **también he intentado con ListPointPlot3D sin resultados** (sólo logro graficar el espectrograma en 2D) , pero acá importan un archivo **.WAV**

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4017/computing-and-plotting-a-spectrogram-in-mathematica

> **Adjunto** el link del archivo ruido.scv (archivo de valores separadas por comas) que es el que necesito graficar

https://mega.nz/#!P912VDIT!cRuug34tTVqFO41bc4hhepLfxk4jV5mYCJjwfeTYvLI

> Y por último las lineas de código para importar el archivo a **Wolfram**

```
datosExcel = Import["C:\\ruta_del_archivo.csv"]
datosExcel = datosExcel[[All, 1]]
```

Comment: Podrías agregar a la pregunta el código que usas ?, que función estas usando ? ListPointPlot3D ? https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPointPlot3D.html

Comment: Hola, disculpa la demora en mi respuesta, estoy usando ListPointPlot3D pero no me ha dado resultado, no entiendo realmente cuales son los parámetros que debo utilizar para poder graficar mi arreglo (el cual tiene solo una columna con datos)

Comment: Si no tiene por qué ser con Mathematica, *en principio* debería ser posible usando matplotlib y mayavi, pero no he podido hacer que funcione.

Comment: mirando el csv, solo veo 2 columnas, entonces ¿cuáles son los componentes del tercer eje? ¿cero? entonces sería plano, dos dimensiones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es la distribución de los datos, para usar **ListPointPlot3D** se debe ajustar a un formato. Así que primero, con los datos que se tiene debe saber que es cada dato, descargué los datos y como no son divisibles exactamente en tres partes asumo que no son datos de coordenadas (x,y,z).

La idea supongo que es que cada valor representa una magnitud en z, entonces a cada valor habrá que asociarle una coordenada (x,y), si se asume la base de la superficie es un cuadrado en (x,y) , entonces descartando algunos datos se puede ajustar los datos al formato adecuado (x,y,z) y así obtener la gráfica con el siguiente código:

```
directorio = NotebookDirectory[]; (*Obtiene el directorio donde está este notebook*)
datosExcel = Import[directorio <> "ruido.csv"];(*El archivo está en el mismo directorio*)
datosExcel = datosExcel[[All, 1]]; 
nD = Length[datosExcel];(*Número de datos*)
n =  IntegerPart[Sqrt[nD]]
Flatten[Table[{j, i, datosExcel[[j + (i - 1)*n]]}, {i, n}, {j,n}], 1] // ListPointPlot3D
```

Si se usa el comando **ListPlot3D** a cambio de **ListPointPlot3D** el resultado se ve mejor. Para hacer el código menos oscuro la última línea se puede replantear usando:

```
datosFormateados=Flatten[Table[{j/10, i/10, datosExcel[[j + (i - 1)*n]]}, {i, n}, {j,n}], 1]
ListPlot3D[datosFormateados, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"]
```

Y como estaba interesante, haciendo un análisis de fourier a la información, es claro que se aprecia una frecuencia dominante en el armónico 7, en otras palabras, es como si cada 7 partes de los datos la información es semejante, por lo mismo si se desean apreciar los datos con una regularidad mejor se puede hacer el gráfico segmentándolo en 7 filas y graficándolas:

```
datosFormateados = Flatten[Table[{j, i, datosExcel[[j + (i - 1)*nD/7]]}, {i, 7}, {j, nD/7}], 1];
ListPlot3D[datosFormateados, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"]
```

El resultado se ve genial, me has dado algo con que entretenerme esta mañana.

[image: Imagen obtenida partiendo los datos en 7 filas]

Comment: Creo que el mayor problema es qué son los datos de cada columna y que quiere hacer con ellos. Si lo que se quiere ver es el espectro de los datos suministrados en la columna uno es otra cosa.